Why are the outputs of a CCZ factory so high?
In https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916, the CCZ factory looks like this (minus the lower-distance T factories):

Why are the outputs so high? It seems like they could be "used", i.e., directly sent to other parts of the circuit as soon as they exit the main body of the distillation. Even if they need stabilizer information from the measurements, the outputs still appear 2 rounds after the green measurement blocks, instead of 1 round.

You need to wait for the decoder to error correct the measurements determining if the output should be kept or discarded. That could take tens of microseconds.
Raising the output gives the decoder more time.

So if the parameters are tuned such that I have only a tiny risk of discarding the output, could I use the output sooner? That is, unless I have another delayed-choice measurement to do based on the CCZ factory measurement results, couldn't I attach a pipe earlier?

No, you can't do that. When you discard a state, it's because you're not sure what it is. If you attach that state to the rest of your computation and only then realize that you should have discarded it, you have probably destroyed the computation. You just performed a gate that you don't know what it was. This happens rarely and you probably have a pretty good guess at what it was, but the overall reliability is as if you made the magic state factory have quadratic suppression instead of cubic. It's an enormous loss in reliability.

Right, I mean a tiny enough risk that there's little chance of any discarding over the full computation. In https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08916, Figure 16, I don't see any discarding: the CCZ outputs are piped right into the adder.

@SamJaques The risk of discard is small, but still orders of magnitude larger than the required error rate. Like, 1 in a million instead of 1 in a billion. I agree Figure 16 is a bit misleading, because the CCZ states appear to come from the middle of the red box instead of the top. The intent is that they are certified as don't-need-to-discard before they leave the factory area.

Ah, so you wouldn't modify the layout since this happens so infrequently, but you'd instead maybe "freeze" the computation and just do another CCZ (the overhead being negligible if these happen at a rate of 1 in a million). This feels weird to me since the reaction depth means the "freeze" would take some time to propagate. So half the computer would be out-of-sync relative to what Figure 16 describes.

@SamJaques You might also keep one or two backup states next to the factory in order to prevent such a freeze. There's intentionally enough unused space in that diagram to fit little extra things like that. But as you note the actual rate of stalling is so low that it doesn't really matter for a time estimate.
